# How to find the median for an array of numbers for java?

Tags: java, arrays, median

```
public double median(){
double input =0;
double answer =sum() * (input) / data.length;
    return answer;
    }
```

This is my code I have for median but it keeps returning as zero when I run the program. The array of numbers are: {3.0, 15.0, 7.0, 27.0};

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute the mean and not the median.

Comment: Your input is always 0.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you've provided it looks like you're trying to find the **mean** not the **median**. I've provided some code below that should help with finding the mean. To find the median you'd need to sort the array, which is a little more complicated.

The short answer is to remove the input=0 line. Assuming that data is a public variable and that sum is a function that sums that public variable your code should work.

The implementation should depend on the context, but I would recommend a static function that takes an array of doubles as the single argument.

```
public class Median{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      double numbers[] ={1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
      System.out.println(median(numbers));
   }
   public static double median(double[]x){
      double sum = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
         sum += x[i];
      }
      return sum/x.length;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You always multiply by zero (input = 0). So it will always return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public Double average(Double[] array){
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for(int index=0;index<array.length;index++){
        sum+=array[index];
    }
    return sum/array.length;
}
```